# How to load resources from disk or memory when using express with ejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, ejs

I'm using **Firebase** hosting to serve my website content by **Express** and **Ejs**.

How to load resources (CSS, Javascript, Images, Fonts) from disk or memory instead of request resources each time user request templated page ?

In other format "**How to change status code from 304 to 200 (from disk cache) ?**".

[image]

index.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= PageTitle %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/reset.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/icons.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/plyr.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/styles.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= PageTitle %></h1>
    <script src='assets/js/jquery.min.js'/>
    <script src='assets/js/plyr.js'/>
    <script src='assets/js/scripts.js'/>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {  
  res.render('index', { PageTitle: "Homepage" });
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "functions/views",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use `redis` to cache your responses or maybe use nginx as a reverse proxy but I don't know if the second option is viable since your app is hosted on firebase or whatever

Comment: Thanks @C.Gochev for help!
 I figured out the issue, I was using `functions/views` in `public` at `firebase.json` and it should be `functions/public`.